# Create an extensible objects with fixed size objects in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create an extensible area in HTML/CSS (only!).

The width of this extensible area can vary between 0 and 50% on the container. The width of the container can vary from 0 to 100% (size of the window).

I have 2 items which should stay stuck to the right of the red item, 100px each.

If the window size is below 200px, only fixed items are visible.

This is almost what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/UsNmU/

The issue is, the blue and green objects stay on the right, I want them on the right of the red object, stuck.
And those item have to stay together (green on the right of the blue)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item1">
        <form>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
}
#content #item1 {
    background: #f00;
    width: 50%;
}
#content #item1 input {
    width: 80%;
}
#content #item2 {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
#content #item3 {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

An image to illustrate:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to remove the 50% width from item 1 and set the left and right offset with absolute positioning.

```
#content #item1 {
    background: #f00;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:200px;
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/UsNmU/2/)

If it's the extensible area is never meant to get bigger than 50%, then you can always add the 50% back as a `max-width`.

```
#content #item1 {
    background: #f00;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:200px;
    max-width:50%;
}
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know max-width would still work if left and right are set. This still doesn't take into account that the question asked that the fixed width boxes stick to the side of the flexible red box at all times -even when the flexible box is no longer filling all available space. Adding max-width back in to this example and then expanding the window shows the small boxes still float right and a gap appears between them and the flexible box. This isn't what was asked for - but seems as this answer has been marked as correct, maybe the user didn't need that after all...

Comment: That's not how I initially understood the question, but looking again now, your interpretation does make more sense. To achieve that, I guess I would put the `max-width` on the content div along with a 200px padding (left or right) to provide the extra space for items 2 and 3. Then you can just absolute position everything relative to the content div. But the OP seems happy with the current solution, so maybe my initial interpretation was correct, or at least good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly your question, I think I have it...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UsNmU/1/)

Well, I have floated all `div`to left, instead of right. That makes the green and blue boxes always stay stack to the red one. I have been made a change in your sintax, too, placing the red `div` before the other ones.

Hope this helps! :)

Edit: Oh, I forget "green on the right of the blue". In that case I suposse that we could change the markup again, placing the green `div`before the blue one.

Comment: The problem here, green and blue objects are going underneath. I want them staying on the right of the red object.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to compress the red one to the maximum possible... I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the left side and giving the right side overflow hidden:

http://jsbin.com/agotug/1/edit

```
.right {
  max-width:50%;
  float:left;
  border:solid;
}
.left {
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid;
}


  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything he asked for. In your example the left box flexes when content is added, not when the window expands. The box on the right you have filling the remaining space when he asked that they have a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

To get what your diagram shows (the red box flexes from between 0% and 50% of the container, the other two boxes are a fixed width and sit next to the red box) I would float everything left and use `calc` and `max-width` to set the width of the red box

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="item1">
        <form>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
}
#content #item1 {
    background: #f00;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    max-width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#content #item1 input {
    width: 80%;
}
#content #item2 {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#content #item3 {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FW4CM/1/

The `calc` width on the red box sets it to 100% - 200px as each of your fixed width boxes are 100px wide. The `max-width` 50% rule stops it from expanding above 50% of the width of the container.

Comment: there are far simpler methods to get 100%-200px without using a css property which isnt supported in 30% of browsers.

Comment: yes there are, such as making width 100% (default value so wouldn't have to actually write that) on a block element and adding margin-right:200px. However given the requirement is it only fills the space up until the point that it reaches 50% of the container, the question can't be reduced down to 'what is a method to get 100%-200px'.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate method would be to use a media query. 
HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="item1">
        <form>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="extra_container">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <div id="item3"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
#content #item1 {
    background: #f00;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    left:0;
    right:200px;
}
#content #item1 input {
    width: 80%;
}
.extra_container{
    float:right;
}
#content #item2 {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
#content #item3 {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 401px){
    #content #item1{
        right:50%;
    }
    .extra_container{
        float:left;
        margin-left:50%;
    }
}
```

What this does is it uses absolute positioning to set both the left and right sides of the red div. This means the div will expand to fit the size between these two coordinates. By default the css is telling it to stretch from 0px from the left edge of the container to 200px in from the right edge of the container. This gives you the shrinking size for when the window is 400px or less and the fixed width elements need to force the red div narrower. The fixed width divs are in a div that is just floated to the right.

The media query comes in to play once the window is over 400px wide. It forces the red div to go from 0px in from the left to 50% in from the right making it 50%. The other two divs container switches to floating left and has a margin of 50% so it sits next to the edge of the red div.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FW4CM/2/

Note this way involves wrapper divs 2 and 3 in another container. This is because I'm switching the float from left to right via a media query and if I applied that directly to them they would get switched around (so 3 would display before 2).

Personally I prefer my calc method as it is simpler and would work even if you decided to nest the elements within another part of the site. However if you are targeting older browsers, media queries do have better support for them:
media query support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries
calc support: http://caniuse.com/calc

Finally I would say flex-box is probably the 'best' way to approach this but support isn't good enough that I would recommend it without knowing your exact requirements. May be worth looking into though.